# Apache Zeppelin Python UDF into SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to get a function that I wrote in python to add a new column into an SQL table. I can't figure out how to pass a UDF from that function to the SQL table. I believe that the way to do this is **withColumn**, I just don't know how to.

The goal is to grab the day/week/year from the SQL table and calculate the month from the given data. The function below works if I set day/week/year equal to values.

Here is the Function:

```
def getmonth(day,week,year):
x = datetime.strptime('{}_{}_{}{}'.format(day,week,year,-0), '%d_%W_%Y%w')
month = x.strftime('%m')
udf(getmonth)
```

The SQL...

```
DriveConfig = sqlContext.sql(""" 
SELECT 
daymade as day,
weekmade as week,
yearmade as year  
FROM datatable2  """)
```

This is what my table looks like roughly, I want to add that month column that is between week and year

`day week year
 2   42   2017
 3   2    2011
 1   14   2005
 ...`

Comment: The real challenge here is that you are not storing dates as dates. You are instead storing all the components independent of each other. You can easily use DATEADD to accomplish this from the data you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def getmonth(day,week,year):
    x = datetime.strptime('{}_{}_{}{}'.format(day,week,year,-0), '%d_%W_%Y%w')
    month = x.strftime('%m')
    return udf(month)

month = udf(getmonth, IntegerType())

DriveConfig = DriveConfig.withColumn("month", month(DriveConfig.day, DriveConfig.week, DriveConfig.year))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines. I changed the column names because reserved words should be avoided as they cause confusion and are more difficult to work with.

```
DECLARE @Something TABLE
(
    MyDay INT
    , MyWeek INT
    , MyYear INT
)

INSERT @Something
(
    MyDay,
    MyWeek,
    MyYear
)
VALUES
(2, 42, 2017)
,(3, 2, 2011)
, (1, 14, 2005)


SELECT DATEADD(day, MyDay, DATEADD(WEEK, MyWeek, CONVERT(CHAR(4), MyYear) + '0101'))
FROM @Something
```